# how to launch chrome/chromium from vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm looking for a shortcut in vim that would launch chrome/chromium and have it always open the same local file ?

ps: on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <F8> :!chrome /path/to/file<CR>
```

The ! command tells vim to run the following command with the shell. In this case, replace `<F8>` by your preferred keystroke and `chrome` by the command which opens chrome/chromium from the shell on your machine (probably `google-chrome`). Obviously, you also have to change the `/path/to/file` to the file you want chrome to open when it starts.